# iis configuration for windows 7 starter 32bit

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

I followed a lot of tutorials for configurate IIS, because I need to see a website build in
  ASP clasic, my problem is that when I try to configure the IIS I can´t see the ASP folder 
  [image]

what im doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about your version of Windows, but on my Win7 Pro English system, it's

> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> ASP

Comment: my problem is that when I go to Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> I can´t see the ASP folder, thanks.

Comment: Given you're in Windows `Starter` edition, I'm surprised Microsoft even allows IIS to begin with. "Starter" is basically the training wheels version of Windows, for extremely cheap/underpowered machines. You'll probably have to upgrade to at least the Home edition, or probably Pro, before you get an ASP option.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, I think you are right, because I can´t create a asp web site

Comment: @suely Check WebMatrix out, it is free and eligible option in Starter editions to develop ASP Classic applications.